# How can I correctly determine the active instances in a circular pool?

Tags: c#, queue

I have a circular pool implementation

```
public class CircularPool<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private readonly Queue<T> instances;
    
    public CircularPool(int size)
    {
        instances = new Queue<T>(size);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            instances.Enqueue(new T());
        }
    }

    public T GetInstance()
    {
        var instance = instances.Dequeue();
        instances.Enqueue(instance); // Circular pool
        return instance;
    }

    public void ReturnInstance(T instance)
    {
        // What does returning look like?
        // Could use IsActive flag?
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetActiveInstances()
    {
        return instances;  // TODO: Only want the active ones
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to keep track of the instances in the pool that are currently in use so I can iterate over them and perform various operations

```
var pool = new CircularPool<Foo>(5);
var fooInstanceA = pool.GetInstance();
var fooInstanceB = pool.GetInstance();
var fooInstanceC = pool.GetInstance();

pool.ReturnInstance(fooInstanceB);

foreach (var activeInstance in pool.GetActiveInstances())
{
    // Do stuff with active instances (fooInstanceA then fooInstanceC)
}
```

How can I correctly obtain the active instances in the order of their age?

Given this is a circular pool then if GetInstance is called more times than the size of the pool without ReturnInstance ever being called then the oldest active instance is returned and becomes the youngest active instance.  This should be reflected accordingly in GetActiveInstances.

Also, what should ReturnInstance look like in the context of a circular pool?

Comment: 'Circular pool' is as far as I know not one of the common data structures. What do you intend to use the datastructure for? What is the contract it has to fulfill? Or do you meant either a ring-buffer or a object pool?

Comment: I think you need another `Queue` to hold the active items.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can use array `T[]` for *all instances* and `HashSet<T>` for *active* ones:

```
public class CircularPool<T> where T : class, new() {
  private readonly T[] m_All;
  private readonly HashSet<T> m_InUse;

  private int m_Index; // Index to start looking for a free instance

  public CircularPool(int size) {
    if (size <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));

    m_InUse = new HashSet<T>(size);
    m_All = Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(_ => new T()).ToArray();
  }

  public bool TryGetInstance(out T availableInstance) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_All.Length; ++i) {
      int index = (i + m_Index) % m_All.Length;

      if (m_InUse.Add(m_All[index])) {
        availableInstance = m_All[index];
        m_Index = index + 1;

        return true;
      }
    }

    availableInstance = default(T); // no available instances found
    return false;
  }

  public T GetInstance() => TryGetInstance(out var result)
    ? result
    : throw new InvalidOperationException("There are no available instances.");

  public bool ReturnInstance(T instance) => m_InUse.Remove(instance);

  public IEnumerable<T> GetActiveInstances() => m_InUse;

  public IEnumerable<T> GetAvailableInstances() => 
    m_All.Where(item => !m_All.Contains(item));
}
```